# Comparing two tables one is mysql db and one is MSSQL db

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server

I am executing the following statement in C#.
There are two tables Orders,Data.
Orders is an mysql Database.
Data is MSSQL Database.

```
insert into orders (orders_id, customers_id, customers_cid, customers_vat_id, customers_name, customers_email_address)
select
    o.*
from
    Test.dbo.orders o
where
    not exists (
        select 1
        from
            CobraDemoData.dbo.Data a
        where
            a.email0 = o.customers_email_address
    )
```

I have created connection strings for the two databases

```
MySqlConnection sqlConn = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;User Id=root;Password = 123456;Persist Security Info=True;database=xtcommerce";)

SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SUBASH-LAPTOP\COBRA;Initial Catalog=CobraDemoData;Integrated Security=True");
```

Can you please tell me what to do next??

Any help would be much appreciated..
Thanks,
Subash....

Comment: Unless MSSQL or mySQL contain linked tables in their database, you will not be able to update using the method you want.  You either have to get all records from one and then loop though updating the other, use LINQ to manage join between different databases, or export from one, import to temp in teh other then to the insert off the temp.  This is not an answer as I don't know HOW to implment, I just know these are a few of the more common options.  Reason: you can't connect to two databases though one connection.

Comment: IF this is a *one-off* type project, you can also import the MySQL data into the MSSQL server into a table and work from there. This way you can do joins on the data etc. If this is a requirement for a long-term project then disregard this suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Open two readers which querying two tables **ordered by the same key** with the similar queries and do comparison row by row, something like that, (assuming there are two connections - mssql and mysql:

```
var sc1 = mssql.CreateCommand();
var sc2 = mysql.CreateCommand();
sc1.CommandText = sc2.CommandText = "select id, name, email, phone from yourtable ORDER BY Id";
sc1.CommandTimeout = sc2.CommandTimeout = 0;

            using (var r1 = sc1.ExecuteReader())
            {
                using (var r2 = sc2.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        bool read1 = r1.Read();

                        if (read1 ^ r2.Read())
                            throw new Exception("Doesn't match!");

                        if(!read1) {Console.WriteLine("MATCH!!!"); break;}

                        for (int i = 0; i < r1.FieldCount; i++)
                        {
                            if (r1.IsDBNull(i) ^ r2.IsDBNull(i))
                                throw new Exception("Doesn't match!");

                            if (string.Compare(r1[i].ToString(), r2[i].ToString(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) != 0)
                                throw new Exception("Doesn't match!");

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

You can then implement your update logic based on this example.

**BUT**

There have to be some unique fields, which identifying rows in both tables